# Software compiled in Visual Studio 6 that runs on Windows 7 crashing on memory read error in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, clistctrl, visual-studio-6

We have a button in our UI that pulls history to a modal. Whenever you click on this button now, in any of our builds , specifically on Windows 10 , the RAM usage surges and the program crashes immediately. Note that this is ONLY happening on Windows 10. Works fine on XP and 7 .

```
LV_COLUMN lvColumn;
lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;
lvColumn.cx = 550;
lvColumn.iSubItem = 0;
lvColumn.pszText = "Description";
m_rcpHistList.InsertColumn(0, &lvColumn);
```

From the above snippet I want to show you what is happening to the variable m_rcpHistList which is a CListCtrl object

```
LV_ITEM lvItem;
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.state = 0;      
lvItem.stateMask = 0;  
int ItmIndx = m_rcpHistList.GetItemCount();
while(OldFile.ReadString(stReadBuf))
{
    lvItem.iItem = ItmIndx;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    //m_rcpHistList.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    m_rcpHistList.SetItemText(ItmIndx, 0, stReadBuf);
    ItmIndx++;
}
OldFile.Close();
```

Here is the bottom of the function where the error is happening specifically on the line that is commented out on the InsertItem function call

When you step over that statement you get an Application error saying

> the instruction at 0x000000076e4adds referenced memory at 0x000000000000001. The memory could not be read

Been trying to untangle this for about two weeks now . Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `**m_rcpHistList.InsertItem(&lvItem);**` -- Do not use `*` to highlight C++ code.  It can get confused with pointers and pointer dereferencing.

Comment: It won't matter, but just for sanity sake, when I did listview work (admittedly a zillion years ago before I wised up and got out of the thankless UI world), I *always* initialized my LV structs zero-filled, e.g. `LV_COLUMN lbColumn = {0};` and `LV_ITEM lvItem = {0};` . Better safe than sorry. That said, possibly relevant: I did notice you're using `LVIF_IMAGE`, but not setting the `iImage` member. That's a bit odd.

Comment: *Note that this is ONLY happening on Windows 10. Works fine on XP and 7*  -- Maybe Windows 10 has unveiled a bug that always existed?

Comment: The LVITEM has more members than the ones you are setting.  Try `LV_ITEM lvItem = {};`.  If that works, then as suspected, you had a bug that always existed, and @WhozCraig was right.

Comment: I am totally impressed by the fact that you compile a 64 bit application with Visual Studio 6. I agree to the Undefined Behavior thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier

Comment: Its not actually haha. Its a 32 bit application

Comment: @OmarAziz Why are you using something from 24+ years ago to build an app that is meant to run on a modern OS?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie your right paul . good catch

Comment: @OmarAziz -- Since you're using VS 6 `ZeroMemory(&lvItem, sizeof(LVITEM));` may be what you should do, since VC6 is using a pre-standard C++11 compiler.  Note that you should do this with all the Windows-based structs before you use them, regardless if you do or don't see it done in the documentation by Microsoft.  Too many times, programmers have been burned by using structs with uninitialized members, and their Windows programs act erratically.

Comment: Wait until they see the costs of making a forced migration that has to make up for 20+ years of build tool neglect because no force on earth can make the software go any further forward. It's an interesting time to be with a company.

Comment: @OmarAziz The mere fact that the company believes that their build tool(s) from a quarter-century ago will not break down once they migrate to a modern operating system is short-sighted.  IMO, your company rolled the dice and were lucky that Windows 7 and XP accepted such a program.  Now you have Windows 10 and 11, and they expect using build tools from last generation will be trustworthy?  Given all the exploits that hackers have come up with?  My last company had to outlaw using VS 2010, due to this reason, and only allow 2015 and above to be used to build apps.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- The company I used to worked for is a financial institution, and they were mandated to drop using VS 2010, due to potential risk using such old build tools that were not being currently updated.   At that time, they went to 2015, and probably now are on 2019.

Comment: Paul and Craig. Much love to you both

Comment: Its been solved. 
by the addition of LV_ITEM lvItem = {0};

Comment: Please create an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that there is a bug . I solved the problem by editing

```
LV_ITEM lvItem;
```

and changing it to `LV_ITEM lvItem = {0};`

The problem lies in Paul McKenzie and WhozCraigs' answers